# Why my getUID always be null?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I made an app that can let user log in and set marker on the google map and the marker connect to a chatroom that belongs to the user who set it.

I use firebase mail authentication ,the problem is that i can't get the uid and it's null,i tried a lot of ways,but it still didn't work.

Actually I can sotre my account data in firebase in createActivity with uid and it work,but when I switch to other activity ,the uid became null,I ask this before and someone told me to use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("uid", currentUid);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

But  it doesn't work.

can someone please help me find where is the problem ,here is my relative code:

**LoginActivity:**

```
public void login(View v){
    final EditText edUserid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eduser);
    final EditText edPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edpass);

    final String email = edUserid.getText().toString();
    final String password = edPass.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "請輸入電子郵件!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "請輸入密碼", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }



    //authenticate user
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // there was an error
                        if (password.length() < 6) {
                            edUserid.setError("密碼太短，請輸入超過6個字元!");
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "登入失敗", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"登入成功",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();


                        String currentUid = user.getUid();
                        intent.putExtra("uid", currentUid);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

**CreateActivity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
public void create(View v){
    EditText Edcount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edcount);
    EditText Edpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edpass);
    EditText Eduser = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userid);
    EditText Edpassag = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edpassag);
    final String email = Edcount.getText().toString().trim();
    final String id = Eduser.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = Edpass.getText().toString().trim();
    String password2 = Edpassag.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "請輸入電子郵件!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "請輸入用戶名!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "請輸入密碼!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (password.length() < 6) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "密碼太短，請輸入超過6個字元!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if(!password.equals(password2)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "密碼前後不符!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }


    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(CreateActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                public void onComplete( Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this, "創建成功，歡迎使用SeeDate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this, "認證失敗或帳號已存在" ,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                        String currentUid = user.getUid();
                        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Contacts/" + currentUid);
                        ContactInfo contact1 = new ContactInfo(email,id,password);
                        myRef.setValue(contact1);//將會員資料寫入FIREBASE
                        Intent intent = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("uid", currentUid);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            });
}
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //get current user

    authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // user auth state is changed - user is null
                // launch login activity

                userUID = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");

            }
            else{
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };


}
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (authListener != null) {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener);
    }
}
}
```

MapFragment(store the marker part):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
             MainActivity a ;
        a = (MainActivity)getActivity();
        a.userUID = userUID1;
            Log.d("TAG", userUID1);
           // userUID = (String) getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().get("uid");
        }

    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);


    return mview;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mMapView = (MapView)mview.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    if(mMapView != null){
        mMapView.onCreate(null);
        mMapView.onResume();
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Map/" + userUID1);
        mFirebaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                LatLng myLatLon = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseMarker.class).toLatLng();

                // stash the key in the title, for recall later

                Marker myMarker = mgoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(myLatLon).draggable(true).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.seedloc2)).title(dataSnapshot.getKey()));

                // cache the marker locally
                markers.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), myMarker);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                LatLng myLatLon = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseMarker.class).toLatLng();

                // Move markers on the map if changed on Firebase
                Marker changedMarker = markers.get(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                changedMarker.setPosition(myLatLon);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Marker deadMarker = markers.get(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                deadMarker.remove();
                markers.remove(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                Log.v(TAG, "moved !" + dataSnapshot.getValue());


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.v(TAG, "canceled!" + databaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });

    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());

    mgoogleMap = googleMap;

    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            // Remove map markers from Firebase when tapped

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
           // String user = ContactInfo.getAccount();
            CustomInfoWindowAdapter adapter = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MapFragment.this);
            googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter);
            marker.setTitle("的種子");
            marker.setSnippet("點選聊天");
            marker.showInfoWindow();
          //  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ChatActivity.class);
           // startActivity(intent);


            return true;
        }
    });

    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(final LatLng latLng) {
            // Taps create new markers in Firebase
            // This works because jackson can figure out LatLng
            mFirebaseRef.push().setValue(new FirebaseMarker(latLng));
        }
    });
    mgoogleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
            // not implemented
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
            // not implemented
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            mFirebaseRef.child(marker.getTitle()).setValue(new FirebaseMarker(marker.getPosition()));
        }
    });


}
```

}

If you need more information,I'll update it.

Comment: did your `FirebaseUser` have an id?

Comment: you mean email auth user id?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
userUID = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
```

with this line:

```
String userUID = user.getUid();
Log.d("TAG", userUID);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't help.
maybe i'll update the MapFragment code .

Answer (score 0):

If I donot miss understand, the `MapFragment` is a part of your `MainActivity`. Your problem comes from this:

```
authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
          userUID = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");

        }
        else{
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
};
```

As I can see, your `userUID` is null until there's an `onAuthStateChanged` changed. To sovlve it, I suggest to move this line to the `onCreate` of `MainActiviy` as your `uid` is passed to `Intent` in previous activity.